# Replacing everything other than alphanumeric, hyphen, period and underscore in a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Here is what I currently use to cleanup filenames with special characters. Basically, it should replace everything other than:

- Alphanumeric a-zA-Z0-9
- Underscores _
- Hyphens -
- Period .

  ```
  echo preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\.\s]/", "", "A\'s`kljdsg\\\`sk//dgj@@@//\/\/\#``flkl_dfd-_-sfsfs-fk kgj.docx");
  ```

Although it seems to work, I am not sure if the _-. is the correct way of using it in a regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-` inside character class denotes range, e.g. `0-9`. So, you should keep it in first, last or escape it if you want to put it in middle.

Also `\w => [A-Za-z0-9_]`

Finally, you can use this regex

```
[^\w.-]
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iP0bR5/1)**

*PHP Code*

```
$re = "/[^\\w.-]/"; 
$str = "A\'skljdsg\\\sk//dgj@@@////#``flkl_dfd-_-sfsfs-fk kgj.docx"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, "", $str);
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/XzT2az)**

If you want to include space also, use

```
[^\w. -]
```

Comment: Selected this as an answer for its descriptiveness. The one provided by Pyton too is accurate.

Comment: `[^\w. -]` with space didn't replace spaces when tried on regex101 any idea?

Comment: @Manju thanks..well if you follow my first line you can modify your own regex

Comment: @Manju if you want to replace space, you should use `[^\w.-]`

Comment: @Manju `[^\w. -]` will remove anything except alpha numerics, `-`, space and `.`..

Comment: `$rex = "/[^\\w._-]/";` is the final regex and it works great.

Comment: @Manju that's mentioned in PHP code..good that it worked for you...:)

Answer (score 1):

If You are using hypen `-` in middle You must escape it by slash:

```
preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-.\s]/", "", "A\'skljdsg\\\sk//dgj@@@////#``flkl_dfd-_-sfsfs-fk kgj.docx");
```

or put it on the end:

```
"/[^a-zA-Z0-9_.\s-]/"
```